# What does "Total Length of columns in constraint is too long" err mean in Informix?

Tags: sql, informix

I get the Total length of columns in constraint is too long. erro from the following

```
sql] Failed to execute:   CREATE TABLE GTW_WORKFLOW_MON ( WORKFLOW_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT
NULL, WORKFLOW_LOADED NUMERIC(20) NOT NULL, ACTIVITY_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FLAGS    
INTEGER NOT NULL, MONITOR_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CLASSNAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, S

TR0 VARCHAR(255), STR1 VARCHAR(255), STR2 VARCHAR(255), NUM0 VARCHAR(255), NUM1 
VARCHAR(255), NUM2 VARCHAR(255), DATE0 VARCHAR(255), DATE1 VARCHAR(255), DATE2 
VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (WORKFLOW_NAME,WORKFLOW_LOADED,ACTIVITY_NAME,MONITOR_NAME) )

  [sql] java.sql.SQLException: Total length of columns in constraint is too long.
```

Comment: Please select the answer that helped you most - if any of them helped at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary key constraint is 785 bytes (255+20+255+255).  If you increase your database page size to 4K it should work, barely.  You should also reconsider if you need your columns to be as wide as you are defining them.

I found a discussion group where an engineer, Radhika Gadde, [describes](http://www.iiug.org/forums/ids/index.cgi/noframes/read/8100) that the maximum index size is related to page size.  He says:

which error you are getting while creation of Tables.
Maximum Index key length can be calculated as follows:

[(PAGESIZE -93)/5] -1

like for 2k it is
[( 2048-93)/5] -1 =[1955/5] -1 =391-1=390

if PAGESIZE is 4K
it is [(4096-93)/5] -1 =4003/5-1=800-1 =799

Comment: Nit pick - NUMERIC(20) is equivalent to DECIMAL(20) and occupies (20/2)+1 = 11 bytes.  But your basic answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is complete. But thought of adding some helpful links in case someone runs to this issue again.
Pagesize on Informix depends on Operating System. On my recent experience, I found it's 4K on Win 2008, OSX - Lion and 2K on SUSE EL4.
You can find the page size by using 'onstat -D'.

I wrote http://sumedha.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-increase-informix-page-size.html with this experience.
Following documentation link from IBM is also very helpful.

[http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.admin.doc%2Fids_admin_0564.htm](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0564.htm)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)